# How to turn off all screensaver/display power saving methods under Scientific Linux 6.1?

Tags: gnome, power-management, scientific-linux

How can I ensure that my screen won't go "black" after given time?

Comment: KDE, Gnome or Terminal?
Please post your X11 configuration.

Comment: sorry, GNOME/GUI. How can I post my X11 config?

Comment: I think that place is pretty generic. **/etc/X11/xorg.conf** as far as I remember. Just post it into your question, then format it with blockquote.

Comment: still can't find that file. :) even the find command can't find it.

Comment: `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` is (mostly) optional nowadays, I suppose this is a **GNOME power management** issue.

Comment: So KDE is not that modern... I use CentOS 5 at work - that should be pretty comparable to Scientific Linux - but it seems GNOME is different there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set this system-wide (and desktop-manager agnostic), you'll want to create an entry in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/ for your monitor, and set: `Option "DPMS"  off`.  Per-user, you could put an `xset dpms off` in the system startup.

Comment: Would be nice if the Linux community could agree to put all the screensaver settings in one place, so it wouldn't take forever to pinpoint the culprit. Day 3 and hoping your answer is the solution ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at GNOME's power mgmt settings, `gnome-power-preferences`, you might stumble upon something similar to this

[image: Power Management Preferences]

(The [GNOME Power management manual](http://library.gnome.org/users/gnome-power-manager/stable/index.html.en) is most helpful, also includes the needed `gconf` keys to maybe automate the process.)

...but increasing the timeout might be enough already?

Also have a look at this FAQ item, [*How do I make my application stop the computer auto-suspending?](http://live.gnome.org/GnomePowerManager/FAQ#How_do_I_make_my_application_stop_the_computer_auto-suspending.3F) hinting at the use of the DBus interface of `gnome-session` to inhibit screen blanking...[this blog entry is a decent write-up](http://www.lucidelectricdreams.com/2011/06/disabling-screensaverlock-screen-on.html), just comment if you need more info on this `:)`

Answer (score 2):

I've racked my brain about this for a while.  I've found the solution that I keep forgetting, so I'm gonna post it.

In your `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file, add this section:

```
Section "ServerFlags"
    Option    "blank time" "0"
    Option    "standby time" "0"
    Option    "suspend time" "0"
    Option    "off time" "0"
EndSection
```

All the other suggestions like `xset` and `xterm` didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

There's a distinction between power management (ACPI/DPMS) and simply blanking the screen. I would assume Scientific Linux has all the same components as other EL6 distributions. Here's what I needed in CentOS and RHEL 6.9:

`gconftool-2 --direct   --config-source xml:readwrite:/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.mandatory   --type bool   --set /apps/gnome-screensaver/idle_activation_enabled false`

It's the Gnome idle activation "feature" that blanks the screen. Of course, there are other ways of disabling this setting such as the Gnome Configuration Editor (if installed):

- Select Applications -> System Tools -> Configuration Editor
- When open, select apps -> gnome-screensaver
- Then on right panel uncheck idle_activation_enabled parameter